# How to do a lazy loaded ionic framework app with a login page

Tags: ionic-framework, lazy-loading, angular-router

I have an app that is working great, but I want to move it behind a login page. The various modules are lazy-loaded and have been working great. However, when I change the app to always go to the login page first (where I will check login status and redirect to the app if logged in), I get an error about routes.

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginPageModule' }
  // this next line was how the app routed before I tried adding the login page
  // { path: '', loadChildren: './tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule' }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

---

login.router.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { LoginPage } from './login.page';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: LoginPage },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class LoginRoutingModule { }
```

---

login.page.ts

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { AppState } from '../_store/store/app.store';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-login',
    templateUrl: 'login.page.html',
    styleUrls: ['login.page.scss'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class LoginPage {

    constructor(private router: Router, private store: Store<AppState>) {
        this.userSubscription = this.store.select(state => state.users.user).pipe(
            filter(user => !!user)
        ).subscribe(user => {
            if (user) {
                // THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR HAPPENS
                this.router.navigate(['/tabs']);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

this.router.navigate(['/tabs']); is where the error happens:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes.
>   URL Segment: 'tabs/behaviors' Error: Cannot match any routes. URL
>   Segment: 'tabs/behaviors'

I'm sure I'm missing something really obvious here. First attempt at lazy loading all the modules. I'm pretty certain I need to reference the tabs module in the login.page file somehow, or in the login.router.module. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The state check for user status works great, I've verified that all of that is working, it is just where it attempts to navigate if user is found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after following a suggestion above, and that giving me the same error, and finding no help in the docs for either angular or ionic, I went on a multi-hour change every combination of routings I could and finally something worked.

These are the routes in the app-routing.module.ts

```
{ path: 'login', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginPageModule' },
{ path: 'tabs', loadChildren: './tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule' },
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
```

---

This is the tabs.router.module.ts before the change that made it work:

```
{ path: 'tabs', component: TabsPage, children: [ .... ] },
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'tabs/behaviors', pathMatch: 'full' }
```

---

This is it now:

```
{ path: '', component: TabsPage, children: [ ... ] },
```

---

That's it. Finally figured it out when accidentally typing in the browser .com:8100/tabs/tabs/behaviors worked. Removing the path: 'tabs' in the tabs routing module fixed it. /tabs goes to the tabs routing, and then /behaviors is the child. My code had added a 2nd layer of /tabs in between the 1st and the /behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change to

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'login', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginPageModule' }
{ path: 'tabs', loadChildren: './tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule' }
];
```

With this code `this.router.navigate(['/tabs']);` you are routing to tabs, but you don't have it declare it. This is for the `app.routing.ts` file. Don't understand why you have the `login.router.ts` file.

Comment: This gave me the same exact error I was already having. Which lead me into a multi-hour try every combination I could think of frenzy and finally I got it working... see answer below if curious.